# Memcached using only 64 Megabytes while it's configured to use 8GB

Tags: memcached

In our /etc/memcached.conf, Memcached is configured to use 8GB of memory

```
# Start with a cap of 64 megs of memory. It's reasonable, and the daemon default
# Note that the daemon will grow to this size, but does not start out holding this much
# memory
-m 8192
```

But when I telnet into it and ask for bytes and evictions, I see numbers I dont like (pasting everything as it might help debugging):

```
Trying ::1...
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.
stats
STAT pid 23579
STAT uptime 1392199
STAT time 1480340703
STAT version 1.4.33
STAT libevent 2.0.21-stable
STAT pointer_size 64
STAT rusage_user 690.539930
STAT rusage_system 1084.063224
STAT curr_connections 26
STAT total_connections 14255
STAT connection_structures 84
STAT reserved_fds 20
STAT cmd_get 14934573
STAT cmd_set 8804970
STAT cmd_flush 0
STAT cmd_touch 0
STAT get_hits 6129345
STAT get_misses 8805228
STAT get_expired 14684
STAT get_flushed 0
STAT delete_misses 114360
STAT delete_hits 701
STAT incr_misses 0
STAT incr_hits 0
STAT decr_misses 0
STAT decr_hits 0
STAT cas_misses 0
STAT cas_hits 0
STAT cas_badval 0
STAT touch_hits 0
STAT touch_misses 0
STAT auth_cmds 0
STAT auth_errors 0
STAT bytes_read 58513351245
STAT bytes_written 28630218114
STAT limit_maxbytes 67108864
STAT accepting_conns 1
STAT listen_disabled_num 0
STAT time_in_listen_disabled_us 0
STAT threads 4
STAT conn_yields 0
STAT hash_power_level 16
STAT hash_bytes 524288
STAT hash_is_expanding 0
STAT malloc_fails 0
STAT log_worker_dropped 0
STAT log_worker_written 0
STAT log_watcher_skipped 0
STAT log_watcher_sent 0
STAT bytes 64871751
STAT curr_items 16167
STAT total_items 8804970
STAT expired_unfetched 42190
STAT evicted_unfetched 7199999
STAT evictions 8638320
STAT reclaimed 50859
STAT crawler_reclaimed 0
STAT crawler_items_checked 0
STAT lrutail_reflocked 0
```

As you see, STAT bytes is only 64871751, which AFAIK (google converter) is only 64mb, which is the default.

When I look into /var/log/memcached , I see only one line entry:

```
Failed to listen on TCP port 11211: Address already in use
```

Somehow, I'm guessing a different instance of memcached (using the default 64MB) is preventing the correct one from booting up.

In rails console, when I run Rails.cache.stats, I also get that small number of bytes (64mb).

Any ideias in how to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We found out that we actually had 2 instances of memcached running on the server. The one being loaded was using the 64mb default.